# Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch() on a non-object in, but I can't see any issues at all with the query

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I know this you get this question a lot, but I haven't been able to get this to work with all of the answers on previous questions about the same problem. I've tried testing the query, and it works fine. I've copied and pasted the exact same query on PHPMyAdmin and it worked fine and I get no errors when I execute the query.

Here's my code:

```
                try {
                    $selectProfilesQuery = 'SELECT profile_id, user_id, profile_name, profile_picture_50, profile_tile_cover FROM profile WHERE user_id = :user_id';
                    $prepSelectProfiles = $conn->prepare($selectProfilesQuery);
                    $prepSelectProfiles->bindParam(':user_id', $uid, PDO::PARAM_INT);
                    $prepSelectProfiles->execute();
                    $profilesResult = $prepSelectProfiles->fetchAll();
                }
                catch(PDOException $e) {
                    $conn = null;
                    header('Location: ../errors/error_101.html');
                }

                while ($profiles = $profilesResult->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                    $profileId = $profiles['profile_id'];
                    $profileTileBg = $profiles['profile_tile_cover'];
                    $profileImage = $profiles['profile_picture_50'];
                    $profileName = $profiles['profile_name'];
                }
```

I've tried to find any other error that maybe had anything to do with my query, but whatever I do it keeps giving me two results (which is the desired effect, but should happen inside the application and not in my DB management system).

Who knows what the problem is here? Becuase I'm staring at this code for 30 minutes now and it makes me go nuts.

The error says the problem is on the line with:

```
while ($profiles = $profilesResult->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
```

Comment: well why whould you like to fetch fetched items? ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `$profilesResult = $prepSelectProfiles->fetchAll();` and use `$prepSelectProfiles->fetch()` in while loop.

Or

Do a foreach on the result:

```
foreach($profilesResult as $profiles) {
  //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The [fetch()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php) should be on PDO Object

So take out

```
$profilesResult = $prepSelectProfiles->fetchAll();
```

and change

```
while ($profiles = $profilesResult->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
```

with

```
while ($profiles = $prepSelectProfiles->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
```

`$profilesResult` is an array after u did `$profilesResult = $prepSelectProfiles->fetchAll();` and u are calling `fetch()` using `$profilesResult` 
which is is why its failing

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is different from other questions.

Here you need only understand what are you doing. In this line you are getting an **array**

```
$profilesResult = $prepSelectProfiles->fetchAll();
```

of simple arrays, none of which being an instance of PDO statement

To make this code little saner and less wordy

```
$sql = 'SELECT profile_id, user_id, profile_name, profile_picture_50, profile_tile_cover '
     . 'FROM profile WHERE user_id = :user_id';
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute([$uid]);
$profiles = $stmt->fetchAll();
while (foreach $profiles as $row) {
    extract($row);
}
```

Comment: Well, I'm happy it's not a duplicate then. I wouldn't want to waste anyone's time here, so thx :)

Comment: yes, but it doesn't make your question on topic either

Comment: Looking at your reputation history, it seems that you need to re-read site rules

Comment: I just want help, why can't I just ask for it?

Comment: Well, help can be different. You cannot ask others to do your job for you.

Comment: Okay thx... Now I understand why a lot of people complain about this site... It must be cuz of some j*rks who just can't help and shut up...